# Java GUI swing pause timer

Tags: java, user-interface

I Have a timer in java GUI swing that controls the refresh rate (FPS) of a game. I wanted to make a pause button but I already tried to use timer.stop() and timer.start()
The problem is the .stop() worked but the .start() doesnt work.

Any idea to make a pausing mechanism ??

```
private static Timer timer;
private static Timer enemyTime;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM i already solved this problem 1 minute after i post this question :D
I just use stop() and start() it worked.